# How To Plot Multi Class Roc Curve From True and Predicted Classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, scikit-learn, roc

I want to plot ROC curve for my problem which has 4 classes. I created True and Predicted class lists after training and prediction. Here are my lists.

**true_class list :**
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3,2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]

**predicted_class list :**
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3,
2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]

Comment: There are many questions about muticlass ROC curves on this site already. Have you had a look at them? For instance a 15-seconds search yields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941223/plotting-roc-curve-with-multiple-classes , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37017400/sklearn-metrics-roc-curve-for-multiclass-classification or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547965/computing-auc-and-roc-curve-from-multi-class-data-in-scikit-learn-sklearn ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computing AUC and ROC curve from multi-class data in scikit-learn (sklearn)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547965/computing-auc-and-roc-curve-from-multi-class-data-in-scikit-learn-sklearn)

Answer (score 0):

ROC curves are normally plotted with non-thresholded data, see the sklearn implementation for a binary roc curve. There are also some extensions to multi-class roc curves (which also are normally used with non-thresholded predictions) but there are better metrics out there than that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this since it is binary you should determine what is your positive value in the `roc_curve` i set `pos_label=1` so you should determine it by your self

```
import sklearn.metrics as metrics
falsepr, truepr, threshold = metrics.roc_curve(true_class_list, predicted_class_list,pos_label=1)
roc_auc = metrics.auc(falsepr, truepr)
# method I: plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Receiver Operating Characteristic')
plt.plot(falsepr, truepr, 'b', label = 'AUC = %0.2f' % roc_auc)
plt.legend(loc = 'lower right')
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1],'r--')
plt.xlim([0, 1])
plt.ylim([0, 1])
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Should I edit my labels before plotting? For example if my true class and predicted class are same and 4, will it be considered false since it is not 1?(pos_label = 1 )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a different metric than ROC curves as they don't fit well with the use case.

Comment: That's not a very useful answer. Can you at least suggest some examples?